# Test golang http/1 server sending oversized frames, but shouldn't

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a very simple golang http server app to generate http traffic for some performance testing. There are 4 files containing static content, each ~1mb in size, to be sent in response to http requests from clients on the same network.
In order to keep the response packets sent by the server < 1500 bytes, during setup i'm breaking the files up into chunks of 1420 bytes, and placing the array of chunks in a map with 4 elements, keyed by file. The request handler uses this map to construct responses.
From the documentation, it seems an http.Flusher can be used to force a packet send. The code to do this is below.

I'm seeing expected behavior > 99% of the time, but a handful of packets are way over 1500 bytes. Oversize frames always occur immediately following a client ACK packet, and only a single oversized packet.
So, have I screwed up or possibly seeing a bug?

```
func createHttpServer(cfg common.Config, dir string, port int, cmap *map[string][][]byte) *http.Server {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // for each of the 4 static content files, iterate over the chunks and send a packet for each
    for i := 0; i < len(cfg.Content); i++ {
        location := cfg.Content[i].Location
        mux.HandleFunc(location, func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
            if !ok {
                panic("createHttpServer(): expected http.ResponseWriter to be an http.Flusher")
            }

            w.Header().Add("From: joeblow@test.com", "Date: "+utcNow())
            w.WriteHeader(200)
            flusher.Flush()

            for _, chunk := range (*cmap)[location] {
                if len(chunk) > 1420 {
                    panic("unexpected oversized chunk")
                }
                w.Write(chunk)
                flusher.Flush()
            }
        })

    }
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + strconv.Itoa(port),
        Handler: mux,
    }

    return srv
}
```

**Additional Info:** the original issue applies to testing done on windows. Under linux (same code), there are many large packets. Docs say that by default Nagle's is disabled in golang, and i've verified mtu is set to 1500. what else to check in order to figure out why results of Flush() are being coalesced into jumbo packets?

Comment: The network stack is combining data in it's buffers to create a packet. A short sleep after the flush might help.

Comment: You _cannot_ adjust the TCP packet size from within the go HTTP package, nor can you control the packet size when writing to an established `*net.TCPConn` at all. All you are doing is trying to coax the underlying TCP stack to send what you want, but what you actually need is to configure the TCP stack correctly. In effect there is no such thing as a "tcp packet" at this layer, you need to inspect this at the IP level to see what is really going on, and what may be effecting your network.

Answer (score 0):

based on helpful comments by Cerise Limon and JimB, it is not possible to control the TCP packet size as I attempted to do, so the question is based on wrong assumptions